# How to duplicate sheet data to another while maintaining synchronous when manipulated?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I currently have sheet1 which stores all the main data and I would like to duplicate the data to sheet2, sheet3 and so on. The current code I used to duplicate sheet1 to other sheets is:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheetID","Sheet1!A1:Z")
```

Although it will keep data synchronous across sheets, the problem is when you try to edit on the sheet that has been imported   `=IMPORTRANGE` it will show

```
#REF!

"Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in CELL VALUE."
```

So is there a way to make it so that all sheets will be synchronous while edited simultaneously?

Edit: Using google script or formula are both fine.

Comment: How do you update sheet1 with all the edits?

Comment: Sheet1 is the original sheet, I can update sheet1 without it giving me errors. However, sheet2 and sheet3 are imported from sheet1 thus editing them will give me errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this in AppScript:

```
function copySheet1(){ //Run this once to copy Sheet1 to all the others

  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet-id");
  var all_sheets = sprsheet.getSheets();

  var values = all_sheets[0].getRange("A1:Z").getValues(); //Get values of Sheet1

  for (var i = 1; i < all_sheets.length; i++){
    all_sheets[i].getRange("A1:Z").setValues(values);

 }
}

function onEdit(e) { //This will run with any sheet you edit

  var edited_sheet = e.source.getSheetName(); //Gets the name of the sheet edited
  var all_sheets = e.source.getSheets();

  var range = e.range.getA1Notation(); //Gets the Cell you edited
  var cell_value = e.range.getValue(); //Gets the value of the cell

  for (var i = 0; i < all_sheets.length; i++){ //Iterates over all the sheets and copies the value to the same cell for each one
    var sheet = all_sheets[i];

    if (sheet.getSheetName() != edited_sheet){ //There is no need to rewrite the cell of the sheet edited
      sheet.getRange(range).setValue(cell_value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for, but I ran into a problem where both sheets would have to have the identical rows and column in order for data to be copied over. Also, if I attempt to delete a row from any of the sheets, the other sheet won't recognize the deletion.

Comment: I don't think that's currently possible, as you would need to use the [onChange() trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder) and there is an existing [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38159142) that doesn't allow to get the cells that have been changed. Maybe you could use the onEdit() function to scan all the cells of each Sheet, but it would be very slow and inefficient.